# Search for string in log files (most recent first) and display first occurence found

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The solution is probably simple, but I’m unable to get it after multiple solutions tried.

I want to scan a folder containing log files for a specific string inside the files ("SUCCESS"). I want to get the date of the file containing the most recent "SUCCESS".
Once found, I don’t need to continue the scan of log files. I will after that indicate the number of days since the last success.

To find the most recent "SUCCESS", I tried with ERRORLEVEL:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('dir /b /o:-d *.log') do (
    find /i "SUCCESS" %%a
    if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
        echo %%a
    )
)
```

I also tried with `findstr`, but it didn’t work out either.

I hope someone will be able to help me a bit!
Thanks!

Comment: findstr /i /m /c:"SUCC" *.log 2>nul

This find all the occurence, but I only want the most recent file containing the string...

Comment: place the logic in a function and exit the function on finding most recent instance

Comment: or just exit the loop after the first find (`goto :eof` right after `echo %%a`, still inside the `if` block)

Comment: The easiest way, surely, is to change `if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (` to `if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (`. Batch will substitute the parse-time value of `errorlevel` for `%errorlevel%`, so the `errorlevel` of the latest operation will appear not to change. The  `if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (` interprets the *current* `errorlevel` and if it's [not] greater than or equal to 1, performs the action. Naturally, exit the loop with a `goto` or `exit` after the data hos been `echo`ed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to T3RR0R, it worked.

```
@echo off
chcp 65001

for /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('dir /b /o:-d *.log') do (
    call :ChercheSucc %%a
    )
)

:RienTrouve
echo Pas de succès
pause
exit 1 /b

:TrouveFichier
set FichierTrouve=%~1
echo %FichierTrouve%
echo Trouvé !
pause
exit 0 /b

:ChercheSucc
findstr /i /m /c:"SUCC" %~1 >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 goto TrouveFichier
```